# Identity relating limits of integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm going through a proof and the author uses the fact that,
$$\int_{x+h-1/n}^{x+h+1/n} f(w)\, \mathrm{d}w-\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n} f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w$$
$$=\int_{x+1/n}^{x+1/n+h} f(w) \, \mathrm{d}w -\int_{x-1/n}^{x-1/n+h} f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w.$$
(in context, $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on some interval $[a,b]$, and we actually integrate an extension of $f$ to the entire real line, and $h$ is small enough so that $x+h\in [a,b]$). 
This seems to me to be true via an intuitive look at the integrals (i.e. drawing some pictures of the interval of integration and the corresponding Riemann or Darboux sums), but I cannot figure it out analytically.

So I ask if there are counter examples or for some hints towards a rigorous proof. I must be missing something simple here...

Comment: This is just a few applications of the property $\int_a^b - \int_a^c = \int_c^b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just note that 
$$\int_{x+h-1/n}^{x+h+1/n} -\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n} =\left(\int_{x+h-1/n}^{x+1/n} +\int_{x+1/n}^{x+h+1/n} \right)-\left(\int_{x-1/n}^{x+h-1/n} +\int_{x+h-1/n}^{x+1/n} \right) =\int_{x+1/n}^{x+h+1/n} -\int_{x-1/n}^{x+h-1/n}$$
(with the integrands omitted for brevity's sake).

More generally, whenever you have a statement like this that "seems true" by drawing a picture of the intervals and how they overlap, you can prove it by breaking all the intervals you're integrating over into subintervals so that you can recombine or cancel them the way the picture suggests.